# VARCHAR vs VARCHAR(X)

Tags: sql, sql-server

This results in 'B':

```
DECLARE @NAME VARCHAR(20)=' s'
IF (@NAME IS NULL OR @NAME='')
   SELECT 'A'
ELSE
   SELECT 'B'
```

Whereas, this results in 'A'.

```
DECLARE @NAME VARCHAR=' s'
IF (@NAME IS NULL OR @NAME='')
   SELECT 'A'
ELSE
   SELECT 'B'
```

The only difference is `VARCHAR(20)` vs `VARCHAR`.

What is the reason of this odd behaviour?

Comment: Can you please add info or tag the question with the specific database software and version you are using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sql Server defaults a `VARCHAR` of unspecified length to a [length of 1](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx). And when taken in [conjunction with Microsoft's interpretation of ANSI/ISO SQL-92](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56876/sql-server-auto-trim-of-varchar-value-in-equal-comparison-but-not-like-compariso) [(ref here)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626) which results in padding compared strings to equal length during equality comparisons, resulting in `' '`  being `=` to  `''`, hence the non-intuitive `'A'` in the second test.

Answer (score 0):

VARCHAR needs a size to be specified when there is no size specified it assume that the declaration is of one character length.

To confirm this, you can check the length of the variables.

Since, your if condition is checking for '' it satisfies the condition.

```
DECLARE @NAME VARCHAR=' s'
select datalength(@name)

returns 1 

DECLARE @NAME VARCHAR(20)=' s'
select datalength(@name)

returns 2
```